# How to plot error bars in polar coordinates in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I have the following problem: I want to plot some data points in polar coordinates in python, which is easy, using some code like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = 1e04 * np.array([5.31,5.29,5.25,5.19,5.09,4.92,4.67,4.27,3.75,3.56])
theta = 2*np.pi/360 * np.array(list(range(0, 100, 10)))

plt.polar(theta, r, "ro")

plt.show()
```

but I want to add error bars and I don't find any sufficient solution. Is there already some prebuild matplotlib-code? Or does anyone know how to define the error bars properly? As I understand it, the r-error is just a straight line while the theta-error should be a segment of a circle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On limitation of errorbar is that the caps are drawn with `hline` and `vline` collections so the caps to not properly rotate in polar coordinates (there is an issue open for this, https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/441 ).  An approximate workaround is to just make the caps have zero size:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(polar=True)

r =  np.array([5.31,5.29,5.25,5.19,5.09,4.92,4.67,4.27,3.75,3.56])
theta = 2*np.pi/360 * np.array(list(range(0, 100, 10)))

ax.plot(theta, r, "ro")
ax.errorbar(theta, r, yerr=1, xerr=.1, capsize=0)

plt.show()
```

[image: polar plot with error bars]

If you want the theta error bars to be circular you will have to implement that your self.  The easiest way is

```
th_err = 1

for th,  _r in zip(theta, r):
    local_theta = np.linspace(-th_err, th_err, 15) + th
    local_r = np.ones(15) * _r
    ax.plot(local_theta, local_r, color='k', marker='')

plt.show()
```

For small errors this won't really make a difference, but will matter for large errors.

Comment: As of [matplotlib version 3.7](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.7.0.html#polar-plot-errors-drawn-in-polar-coordinates) the error bars are automatically curved.

Answer (score 0):

I would have recommended something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(polar=True)

r = 1e04 * np.array([5.31,5.29,5.25,5.19,5.09,4.92,4.67,4.27,3.75,3.56])
theta = 2*np.pi/360 * np.array(list(range(0, 100, 10)))

ax.plot(theta, r, "ro")
ax.errorbar(theta, r, xerr=0.5, yerr=0.4)

plt.show()
```

But there seeems to be some problem. I dont know if it is inherent to `pylab`. Kind of at a loss as to what to do :)